# Why isn't present participle correct in "feeling both personal and cultural"?

Tags: exam-questions, syntax, participles

In an ACT English test:

> Dismayed by the loss, ___　both personal and cultural, Santiago responded through his art.

Why is "which felt" the accepted one for filling the blank while not "feeling" ?

I think when "feeling" is used, I have a participle clause–"feeling both personal and cultural–which has the logical subject "Santiago." It sounds right to me: Santiago felt both personal and cultural about the loss.

Comment: Why should the relative clause be restrictive? There's no implication that Santiago was dismayed by more than one loss, so a restrictive relative clause is inappropriate here.

Comment: Because the author has specified "the loss," the relative clause describing it, I think, is essential to the antecedent, so a restrictive clause is required here. Idk, I may have some misunderstanding about this.

Comment: The definite article is irrelevant here. If it was "a loss", then a restrictive relative may be appropriate. See also my last comment.

Comment: and Could you tell me why "feeling" is not acceptable ?